# Woocommerce where to set the Price Suffix

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, production

Short question but where in de woocommerce/wordpress environment can I define the "get_price_suffix();" function per product?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on the *Tax* settings page and is  `wp_options.woocommerce_price_display_suffix` in the database.

Please use the [official site](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us) for WooCommerce and third-party plugin support, rather than StackExchange.